# Query generated mongo-version collection without model

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to use [mongoose-version](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-version) to track and keep changes in mongodb.

I created this example schema.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var version = require('mongoose-version');

var PageSchema = new Schema({
    title : { type : String, required : true},
    tags : [String],
});

PageSchema.plugin(version, { collection: 'Page__versions' });

const PageModel = mongoose.model('PageModel', PageSchema)
```

So all versions are stored in collection `Page__versions`, but how can I query this collection, because I don't have a model for that collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the collection you can use the mongoose database object that is returned from the `createConnection` function. So when you start the application you store this variable like this

```
let db = mongoose.createConnection(url, params);
```

And then you can use this object to get the collection you want, in this case

```
let collection = db.collection("Page__versions");
```

At this point you can use the standard methods to do CRUD operations on that collection, for example if you want to find all documents that have a specific property in that collection, you can do something like this

```
collection.find({myProperty: value});
```

And this will give you all documents that are in that collection that matches the criteria.

If you don't know the model you can always get one item from the collection and see what the result is

```
let doc = collection.findOne({}); //This will get the first document in the collection
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you know how to populate some fields?

I use `mongoose.connection.collection('Page__versions').findOne({ refId: ObjectId(pageId) })
    .populate('_author')` but I get "[,,,].populate is not a funciton"

Comment: I believe that is only possible using mongoose models. If you want to achieve the same thing the best I can think is to use the [aggregation framework](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/aggregate.html)